# How to keep divs from breaking while keeping them centered

Tags: html, css

I've got a red box and a green one, side-by-side, and centered. When the browser width is smaller than the  width of the squares, they break into separate lines. How do I keep them together?

(I tried using a container div with their combined widths, which does the job in keeping them together, but they no longer are centered.)

Any suggestions?

The code:

```
  <body>
    <div style='text-align:center;font-size:0'>
        <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:red;width:200px;height:50px'></div>
        <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:green;width:200px;height:50px'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

You can run it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/2De21ziNmaeleFmkPuPF?p=preview

Comment: Add `min-width:400px; margin: 0 auto;` to your outer div...

Comment: @War10ck For `margin: 0 auto` to work you need a width smaller than viewport (or its parent) and in this case that will never happen ... and for the `min-width`, an answer is already given, so maybe better to upvote such answer instead of answer with a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in many ways, here is 3:

Use `min-width`

```html
<div style='text-align:center;font-size:0; min-width: 400px'>
  <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:red;width:200px;height:50px'></div>
  <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:green;width:200px;height:50px'></div>
</div>
```

Use `white-space: nowrap`

```html
<div style='text-align:center;font-size:0; white-space: nowrap'>
  <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:red;width:200px;height:50px'></div>
  <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:green;width:200px;height:50px'></div>
</div>
```

Use `display: flex;`

```html
<div style='text-align:center;font-size:0;display: flex;justify-content: center'>
  <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:red;width:200px;height:50px'></div>
  <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:green;width:200px;height:50px'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Flex-box

```css
.parent{
display:flex;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:500px;
}

.parent div{
background:green;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div>cell1</div>
  <div>cell2</div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using `width: 50%` on the boxes instead of `width: 200px`.

Answer (score 0):

If you give them a fixed width (ex 200+200px), when that div width is passed (ex mobile width of 375px < 400px of divs sum), the last element slide on the next row.

With width of 35% for each other, will look exactly as you want it for that 200px.

```
  <body>
    <div style='text-align:center;font-size:0; width: 100%;'>
      <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:red; width:35%;height:50px'></div>
      <div style='display:inline-block;background-color:green; width:35%;height:50px'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

[Here is the link to your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/4e47puupxwYvjfXbbCMx?p=preview)

EDIT:

Here is a usefull link for understanding better the width options depends of the width of device, and I encourage you to take a deeply look inside of w3schools, or other platforms where you can learn better how to manipulate elements of html, with css and js.

[screen-width](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_breakpoints)